# Backend error on import from Cloud Storage to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Recently, we have begun to see a number of errors such as this when importing from Cloud Storage to BigQuery:

Waiting on job_72ae7db68bb14e93b7a6990ed628aedd ... (153s) Current status: RUNNING 
BigQuery error in load operation: Backend Error

Waiting on job_894172da125943dbb2cd8891958d2d10 ... (364s) Current status: RUNNING 
BigQuery error in load operation: Backend Error

This process runs hourly, and had previously been stable for a long time. Nothing has changed in the import script or the types of data being loaded.  Please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up these jobs in the BigQuery logs-- both of them appear to have succeeded. It is possible that the error you got was in reading the job state. I've filed an internal bug that we should distinguish between errors in the job and errors getting the state of the job in the bq tool.

After the job runs, you can use `bq show -j <job_d>` to see what the actual state of the job is. If it is still running, you can run `bq wait <job_id>`.

I also took a look at the front-end logs; all of the status requests for those job ids returned HTTP 200 (success) codes.

Can you add the `--apilog=file.txt` parameter to your bq command line (you'll need to add it to the beginning of the command line, as in `bq --apilog=file.txt load ...`) and send the output of a case where you get another failure? If you're worried about sensitive data, feel free to send it directly to me (tigani at google).

Thanks /
Jordan Tigani /
Google BigQuery Engineer